# How to fix Blender Texture paint?

Tags: texture-painting

First of all let me just say I'm new to blender and I may be doing something wrong but after an 1 or 2 on google I've haven't found any answers.

Whenever I use texture paint in blender I have 2 consistent problems.

1. When I use Blender Texture paint the image on the left side is always a blank grey even when my mesh on the right has colour.
2. If I attempt to use draw and paint on the left or right Blender will freeze. I can wait 20 or so seconds and it will unfreeze and maybe 50% of the time my last action before freezing will show up.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Are you using Mirror modifier?

Comment: Nup, I've only used solidify and subdivision

Answer (score 0):

I'm new myself but have you tried:

1. Is the correct image selected on the left side. At the top of the page you can select what image to display (next to the buttons for view, brush, image).
2. Do you have rendered view selected on the right and Blender has to render everytime you change something?

Again I'm new myself but this is what I thought of.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, but checked both of those and neither are the problem as I have solid view and I do have an image selected but it still shows up as blank and grey.

Comment: Has to be the exact image you are using in the model to paint to, must also match the image showing in the active texture slot in the paint tool.

Comment: I've checked these and I'm using the exact same png everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 11 it actually has alot of issues, try using 10 for now, second freezing might be because you have a network location in your blender recent history, open a new scene in the Recent section clear history.

Also painting texture maps in blender is teadious and I don't advice you to do instead try substance painter.